# How to show a real Admob ad rather than the test ad?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I wrote this piece of code with Swift so that when I push a button an Admob ad shows up, and now my app is showing a test Admob ad. My question is how I can transition from showing a test ad to a real world ad? I'm using the simulator on Xcode by the way since I don't have an iPhone!

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import GoogleMobileAds

class NewsPageViewController: UIViewController {
var interstitial:GADInterstitial!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
}

func createAndLoadAd() -> GADInterstitial {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    var request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
    interstitial.loadRequest(request)
    return interstitial
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
    }
```

}

Comment: try to remove  "request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]"

Comment: Thanks I tried that. Also, I noted that the adUnitID I was using i.e. "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"  was the default one in google'e tutorial. I created a new app in my Admob account and got a new adUnitID. Then, replaced it with the default one. But, now the problem is instead of an ad, a full black screen is showing up! Not sure, why I'm getting a black screen rather than an ad now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

1-remove "request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]

2- Create an Admob account on google's website, then create an app in your account,then, replace the default adUnitID given in the google's tutorial with the one in the created app.

3- Then, instead of test ad, you might get a full black screen ad. This one is because it takes a few hours before google starts to send real ads. Hope that helps.

Comment: Bear in mind that you should never use anything but test ads when building and testing your application. Otherwise you'll be in violation of AdMob policy and possibly end up with a suspended account.

Comment: Oh shoot I didn't know that and I have already opened an ad for maybe 50-60 times during the testing of my app! Is my account going to be suspended then?!

Comment: 2 days gone still testing ads display. I have already remove testDevices. Any suggestions for me.